# Javascript and Regular Expressions to import a CSV file

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is one raw line of text imported from CSV:

```
10,"2013-04-17 16:29:36",out,"BTC sold: [tid:0450750450454505] 0.85985758 BTC at 69.88355 € (0.55% fee)",0.85985758,0
```

The code I'm trying to edit is fairly simple and comes from [this tutorial page][1] (*copy of main code is at bottom of this page):

The main regexp code part is:

```
var objPattern = new RegExp(
  (
    // Delimiters.
    "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

    // Quoted fields.
    "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

    // Standard fields.
    "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
  ),
  "gi"
);
```

What I want is, in the raw line text I copied at the beginning, I want to delete or ignore what is between brackets, parenthesis () and make the word "at" a delimiter for a new column. When I import the CSV, the value of the new column would be what's after the word "at".

The equivalent regexp code should be:
    [(.*?)]|((.*?))
and
    (\bat\b)

I tried various options like adding (\bat\b) to the regexp in the delimiters sections, however it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Whole Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}

function search() {
  // Prompt the user for a search term
  var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the string to search for:");

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
  var headers = [["File Name", "File Type", "URL"]];
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);

  // Search the files in the user's Docs List for the search term
  var files = DocsList.find(searchTerm);

  // Loop through the results and display the file name, file type, and URL
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getName());
    sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getType());
    if (files[i].getType() == "document") {
      urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=";
    }
    else if (files[i].getType() == "spreadsheet") {
      urlBase = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=";
    }
    else if (files[i].getType() == "presentation") {
      urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=";
    }
    else {
      urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=";
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(urlBase + files[i].getId());
  }
}

function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = "history_BTC.csv";


 var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";



  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();

      break;
    }
  }

  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}

// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || "," );


  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\bat\b|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"

    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;


  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }


    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }


    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
}
```

Comment: Have you considered simply using `\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)` to replace in the input string with "" and then replacing `/\bat\b/g` with a proper delimiter `,` before you process with that function

Answer (score 0):

First, replace " at " with ",". Not need for regexes for this.

Then it's a simple replace:

```
a=myString.replace(" at ", ",");
b=a.replace(" at ", ",");
c=b.replace(/(\[[^\]]+\]|\([^)]+\))/gi, "");
```

Comment: Im starting to understand the logic, thanks :) Could you tell where to paste this so i don't spend many more hours on this please ?

Comment: Also myString has to be changed ? I've tried many hours without success. Thanks for all the help anyway.

Comment: I'm still trying to make this work with dda's advice, however i don't know where to put the code exactly. Also i think i have to replace myString by something, probably csvData or csvFile, but i get errors like "TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object", and Im pretty sure the code provided should perfectly work but Im too bad at javascript.